# How does one NOT save Messages history upon new login in El Capitan on iMac?

Tags: messages, macos, text, ios

"save history when conversations are closed"

That is a preferences option in Message app on El Capitan. I do NOT have this box checked, yet every time I log into Messages EVERY conversation from at least the last week, if not longer, populates the app. How do I get this to stop happening and start fresh each new login session? And is it possible to have the Messages app synced with the iOS Messages for when I delete a conversation - having it deleted on both?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you logging in and out so frequently? Messages don't save if you log out. You can right click in the conversation and delete it.

Comment: Thx for responding. I login once in the morning and logout late at night - not very frequent. The messages DO save when I logout, hence my posting this question. Perhaps it is a glitch or some setting that I am missing. That is what I am trying to get help figuring out.

Comment: Why do you log out of Messages every day? It's designed to stay logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the interest in my logging in and logging out habits...but they are irrelevant to the question that is the topic and title of this post. If you have an answer to the issue I am looking to solve, I would love to hear it.

Comment: When you log out of iMessage, it removes the files related to messaging. I don't know why it's saving. The pref you have unchecked is designed to keep the messages after you press the X on the conversation. When you press the X, do the messages come back if you restart the Messages app?

Comment: I have this same issue. I have the box UNchecked for iMessages to be saved on my MacBook, however, the messages are still archived. I thought perhaps it was because I had both e-mail and phone-number linked to the account, so now I only have the phone number linked to my iMessage. I don't know if this has discontinued the issue, though... This has been ongoing for a long time.

Comment: Yes, they come back. That is the issue I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The pref doesn't say "Save history when you quit or logout" it says "Save history when conversations are **closed**" - i.e., when you hit the X to get rid of them - either permanently, or temporarily, depending on that pref.

If you want to delete the archive itself, you'd have to do that manually.
Files live in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages`